# Cmd file to run executable in a folder of an archived zip file

Tags: cmd, zip

I have two files which I want to archive. I.e a zip file. Files contained in the archive would be a cmd file and a folder containing the file to run. 
I want a cmd script to use to run the file in the folder when the archive file is opened and the cmd file is runned. Would prefer cmd to run silently with no pop up screen.

Can anyone help with the cmd script here?

Comment: People here are happy to help with getting your code to work. But, SO is not a free code writing service. Please take the tour to learn how SO operates. https://stackoverflow.com/help Questions without source code should go to https://superuser.com/ Secondly, automatically running something when an archive is opened sounds like a useful capability for malware.

Comment: I am a new user to stackoverflow. And the code is for a course I’m taking under cyber security.

Comment: This was the first thing that appeared from a Google search. https://superuser.com/questions/879018/can-a-zip-file-auto-execute-files-from-inside-it

Comment: The goal here isn’t auto execute. There is a user interaction with the cmd file which would link to the file in the folder of the Achieve file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Vbs script to use in running this file.

```
Run.vbs
file.exe
```

Run.vbs script should be like this.

```
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "file.exe"
set wshNetwork = CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )`enter code here`
strUserName = wshNetwork.UserName
WScript.Sleep (10000)
X=MSGBOX("File runs successfully" ,0, "Alert For: " & strUserName)
WScript.Interactive = true
```

Line 4 - 7 ain't compulsory for this task. Its just to locate the Computer Username and display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that two (2) files are extracted into a directory.

```
RUNME.CMD
DOIT.EXE
```

The RUNME.CMD, if it is run, can refer to the directory where it is located.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO My directory is "%~dp0"
IF EXIST "%~dp0DOIT.EXE" ("%~dp0DOIT.EXE")
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Working but i have an amendment to your code base on question and the black command prompt windows still pops up. Tried with a vbs script and there was no pop up though

Comment: Glad to hear you got something to work. I do not know how to eliminate the console window with a .cmd script. Would you mind posting your VBS script. I am not sure why you copied my answer to another answer. Is there a remaining question?

Comment: I didn't wan't to get your answer edited. You can edit that and i delete that. I also found a way around .cmd script console window. You create a shortcut to the .cmd script in the same folder and set the main .cmd script file attribute to hidden then you open the file property of the shortcut created and at the Run dialog change from Normal window to minimized and click apply then run. Console window eliminated but the problem with this is shortcut wont get to work on another workstation. Do you have a way around this to make shortcuts work on any work station?

Comment: I do not know a workaround. I think shortcuts (.lnk) contain a path to whatever they are starting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that two (2) files are extracted into a directory.

```
RUNME.CMD
FOLDER with DOIT.EXE
```

The RUNME.CMD, if it is run, can refer to the directory where it is located.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO My directory is "%~dp0FOLDER"
IF EXIST "%~dp0FOLDER\DOIT.EXE" ("%~dp0FOLDER\DOIT.EXE")
EXIT /B
```

Comment: This illustrate how to reference from folder before the main file. That is if RUNME.CMD is not in the same directory with DOIT.EXE. More easier for beginner to grab this now.